# Linking error in mbed-crypto on NUCLEO_L152RE

Tags: c++, linker, embedded, mbed

I am running crypto example code (https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-mbed-crypto) on NUCLEO-L152RE. The program is compiled correctly but there are errors in linking. The error log is given below. I have tried to execute multiple times but the same problem persists. I have installed GNU Tools ARM Embedded in C drive and my programs are in D drive, will it make a difference? I am assuming no since compilation is correct.

```
**Error Log** 
--

D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto>mbed compile --target NUCLEO_L152RE --toolchain GCC_ARM --profile=mbed-os\tools\profiles\debug.json
[mbed] Working path "D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto" (program)
Building project mbedCrypto (NUCLEO_L152RE, GCC_ARM)
Scan: mbedCrypto
Compile [  0.1%]: mbed_tz_context.c
Compile [  0.2%]: MCR20Drv.c
Compile [  0.3%]: rf_configuration.c
Compile [  0.5%]: main.cpp
Compile [  0.6%]: ESP8266.cpp
Compile [  0.7%]: at24mac_s2lp.cpp
Compile [  0.8%]: at24mac.cpp
Compile [  0.9%]: AnalogIn.cpp
Compile [  1.0%]: NanostackRfPhyMcr20a.cpp
Compile [  1.1%]: NanostackRfPhyAtmel.cpp
Compile [  1.3%]: ESP8266Interface.cpp
[Warning] ESP8266Interface.cpp@522,1: 'virtual const char* ESP8266Interface::get_ip_address()' is deprecated: String-based APIs are deprecated [since mbed-os-5.15] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[Warning] ESP8266Interface.cpp@576,1: 'virtual const char* ESP8266Interface::get_gateway()' is deprecated: String-based APIs are deprecated [since mbed-os-5.15] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[Warning] ESP8266Interface.cpp@597,1: 'virtual const char* ESP8266Interface::get_netmask()' is deprecated: String-based APIs are deprecated [since mbed-os-5.15] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
Compile [  1.4%]: NanostackRfPhys2lp.cpp
Compile [  1.5%]: AnalogOut.cpp
Compile [  1.6%]: BusInOut.cpp
Compile [  1.7%]: CAN.cpp
Compile [  1.8%]: BusIn.cpp
Compile [  1.9%]: DigitalIn.cpp
Compile [  2.1%]: BusOut.cpp
Compile [  2.2%]: DigitalInOut.cpp
Compile [  2.3%]: DigitalOut.cpp
Compile [  2.4%]: Ethernet.cpp
Compile [  2.5%]: InterruptManager.cpp
[Warning] InterruptManager.h@204,40: 'CallChain' is deprecated: CallChain has been deprecated and will be removed. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[Warning] InterruptManager.cpp@63,60: 'CallChain' is deprecated: CallChain has been deprecated and will be removed. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[Warning] InterruptManager.cpp@92,32: 'CallChain' is deprecated: CallChain has been deprecated and will be removed. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
Compile [  2.6%]: I2CSlave.cpp
Compile [  2.7%]: PortIn.cpp
Compile [  2.9%]: PortInOut.cpp
Compile [  3.0%]: InterruptIn.cpp
Compile [  3.1%]: ResetReason.cpp
Compile [  3.2%]: MbedCRC.cpp
Compile [  3.3%]: I2C.cpp
Compile [  3.4%]: PortOut.cpp
Compile [  3.5%]: PwmOut.cpp
Compile [  3.6%]: FlashIAP.cpp
Compile [  3.8%]: QSPI.cpp
Compile [  3.9%]: RawSerial.cpp
Compile [  4.0%]: TableCRC.cpp
Compile [  4.1%]: SPISlave.cpp
Compile [  4.2%]: SerialWireOutput.cpp
Compile [  4.3%]: Ticker.cpp
Compile [  4.4%]: Timeout.cpp
Compile [  4.6%]: Timer.cpp
Compile [  4.7%]: SPI.cpp
Compile [  4.8%]: Serial.cpp
Compile [  4.9%]: ByteBuffer.cpp
Compile [  5.0%]: EndpointResolver.cpp
Compile [  5.1%]: TimerEvent.cpp
Compile [  5.2%]: SerialBase.cpp
[Warning] SerialBase.h@357,27: 'mbed::SerialBase::_rx_pin' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
[Warning] SerialBase.h@335,24:   'void (mbed::SerialBase::* mbed::SerialBase::_init_func)()' [-Wreorder]
[Warning] SerialBase.cpp@26,1:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
[Warning] SerialBase.h@358,28: 'mbed::SerialBase::_static_pinmap' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
[Warning] SerialBase.h@335,24:   'void (mbed::SerialBase::* mbed::SerialBase::_init_func)()' [-Wreorder]
[Warning] SerialBase.cpp@44,1:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
Compile [  5.4%]: Watchdog.cpp
Compile [  5.5%]: LinkedListBase.cpp
Compile [  5.6%]: OperationListBase.cpp
Compile [  5.7%]: AsyncOp.cpp
Compile [  5.8%]: UARTSerial.cpp
Compile [  5.9%]: USBCDC.cpp
Compile [  6.0%]: USBAudio.cpp
Compile [  6.2%]: USBHID.cpp
Compile [  6.3%]: USBMIDI.cpp
Compile [  6.4%]: USBDevice.cpp
Compile [  6.5%]: PolledQueue.cpp
Compile [  6.6%]: TaskBase.cpp
Compile [  6.7%]: USBCDC_ECM.cpp
Compile [  6.8%]: USBMSD.cpp
[Warning] USBMSD.h@266,18: 'USBMSD::_bd' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
[Warning] USBMSD.h@234,14:   'uint32_t USBMSD::_addr' [-Wreorder]
[Warning] USBMSD.cpp@67,1:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
[Warning] USBMSD.h@266,18: 'USBMSD::_bd' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
[Warning] USBMSD.h@234,14:   'uint32_t USBMSD::_addr' [-Wreorder]
[Warning] USBMSD.cpp@80,1:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
Compile [  7.0%]: USBMouse.cpp
Compile [  7.1%]: equeue_posix.c
Compile [  7.2%]: equeue.c
Compile [  7.3%]: USBKeyboard.cpp
Compile [  7.4%]: mbed_shared_queues.cpp
Compile [  7.5%]: USBSerial.cpp
Compile [  7.6%]: EventQueue.cpp
Compile [  7.8%]: USBMouseKeyboard.cpp
Compile [  7.9%]: AT_CellularBase.cpp
Compile [  8.0%]: equeue_mbed.cpp
Compile [  8.1%]: AT_CellularContext.cpp
[Warning] AT_CellularContext.cpp@266,39: 'virtual const char* NetworkStack::get_ip_address()' is deprecated: String-based APIs are deprecated [since mbed-os-5.15] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[Warning] AT_CellularContext.cpp@935,35: 'void mbed::CellularDevice::stop()' is deprecated: Use CellularDevice::shutdown() instead. [since mbed-os-5.15] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
Compile [  8.2%]: ATHandler.cpp
Compile [  8.3%]: AT_CellularDevice.cpp
Compile [  8.4%]: APN_db.cpp
Compile [  8.6%]: CellularLog.cpp
Compile [  8.7%]: AT_CellularInformation.cpp
Compile [  8.8%]: CellularUtil.cpp
Compile [  8.9%]: AT_CellularNetwork.cpp
Compile [  9.0%]: AT_CellularStack.cpp
Compile [  9.1%]: AT_ControlPlane_netif.cpp
Compile [  9.2%]: AT_CellularSMS.cpp
Compile [  9.4%]: CellularContext.cpp
Compile [  9.5%]: CellularDevice.cpp
Compile [  9.6%]: GEMALTO_CINTERION_CellularInformation.cpp
Compile [  9.7%]: CellularStateMachine.cpp
Compile [  9.8%]: GENERIC_AT3GPP.cpp
Compile [  9.9%]: GEMALTO_CINTERION_CellularContext.cpp
Compile [ 10.0%]: GEMALTO_CINTERION.cpp
Compile [ 10.1%]: GEMALTO_CINTERION_CellularStack.cpp
[Warning] GEMALTO_CINTERION_CellularStack.cpp@468,27: 'port_start' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
Compile [ 90.0%]: analogin_device.c
Compile [ 90.1%]: analogout_device.c
Compile [ 90.2%]: stm32l1xx_hal_adc_ex.c
Compile [ 90.3%]: ThisThread.cpp
Compile [ 90.4%]: stm32l1xx_hal_comp.c
Compile [ 90.5%]: stm32l1xx_hal_cortex.c
Compile [ 90.6%]: stm32l1xx_hal_crc.c
Compile [ 90.8%]: stm32l1xx_hal_cryp.c
Compile [ 90.9%]: stm32l1xx_hal_cryp_ex.c
Compile [ 91.0%]: stm32l1xx_hal_dac.c
Compile [ 91.1%]: stm32l1xx_hal_dac_ex.c
Compile [ 91.2%]: stm32l1xx_hal_dma.c
Compile [ 91.3%]: stm32l1xx_hal_flash.c
Compile [ 91.4%]: stm32l1xx_hal_flash_ex.c
Compile [ 91.6%]: stm32l1xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c
Compile [ 91.7%]: stm32l1xx_hal_gpio.c
Compile [ 91.8%]: stm32l1xx_hal_i2s.c
Compile [ 91.9%]: stm32l1xx_hal_iwdg.c
Compile [ 92.0%]: stm32l1xx_hal_i2c.c
Compile [ 92.1%]: stm32l1xx_hal_lcd.c
Compile [ 92.2%]: stm32l1xx_hal_nor.c
Compile [ 92.4%]: stm32l1xx_hal_opamp.c
Compile [ 92.5%]: stm32l1xx_hal_irda.c
Compile [ 92.6%]: stm32l1xx_hal_opamp_ex.c
Compile [ 92.7%]: stm32l1xx_hal_pcd_ex.c
Compile [ 92.8%]: stm32l1xx_hal_pwr.c
Compile [ 92.9%]: stm32l1xx_hal_pcd.c
Compile [ 93.0%]: stm32l1xx_hal_pwr_ex.c
Compile [ 93.2%]: stm32l1xx_hal_rcc_ex.c
Compile [ 93.3%]: stm32l1xx_hal_rtc.c
Compile [ 93.4%]: stm32l1xx_hal_rcc.c
Compile [ 93.5%]: stm32l1xx_hal_sd.c
Compile [ 93.6%]: stm32l1xx_hal_rtc_ex.c
Compile [ 93.7%]: stm32l1xx_hal_smartcard.c
Compile [ 93.8%]: stm32l1xx_hal_spi.c
Compile [ 94.0%]: stm32l1xx_hal_spi_ex.c
Compile [ 94.1%]: stm32l1xx_hal_sram.c
Compile [ 94.2%]: stm32l1xx_hal_tim_ex.c
Compile [ 94.3%]: stm32l1xx_hal_tim.c
Compile [ 94.4%]: stm32l1xx_hal_usart.c
Compile [ 94.5%]: stm32l1xx_hal_wwdg.c
Compile [ 94.6%]: stm32l1xx_hal_uart.c
Compile [ 94.8%]: stm32l1xx_ll_adc.c
Compile [ 94.9%]: stm32l1xx_ll_comp.c
Compile [ 95.0%]: stm32l1xx_ll_crc.c
Compile [ 95.1%]: stm32l1xx_ll_dac.c
Compile [ 95.2%]: stm32l1xx_ll_fsmc.c
Compile [ 95.3%]: stm32l1xx_ll_gpio.c
Compile [ 95.4%]: stm32l1xx_ll_dma.c
Compile [ 95.6%]: stm32l1xx_ll_exti.c
Compile [ 95.7%]: stm32l1xx_ll_opamp.c
Compile [ 95.8%]: stm32l1xx_ll_i2c.c
Compile [ 95.9%]: stm32l1xx_ll_pwr.c
Compile [ 96.0%]: stm32l1xx_ll_rcc.c
Compile [ 96.1%]: stm32l1xx_ll_sdmmc.c
Compile [ 96.2%]: stm32l1xx_ll_tim.c
Compile [ 96.4%]: stm32l1xx_ll_spi.c
Compile [ 96.5%]: stm32l1xx_ll_rtc.c
Compile [ 96.6%]: stm32l1xx_ll_usart.c
Compile [ 96.7%]: stm32l1xx_ll_utils.c
Compile [ 96.8%]: system_stm32l1xx.c
Compile [ 96.9%]: USBPhy_STM32.cpp
Compile [ 97.0%]: gpio_irq_device.c
Compile [ 97.1%]: flash_api.c
Compile [ 97.3%]: pwmout_device.c
Compile [ 97.4%]: spi_api.c
Compile [ 97.5%]: analogin_api.c
Compile [ 97.6%]: serial_device.c
Compile [ 97.7%]: analogout_api.c
Compile [ 97.8%]: can_api.c
Compile [ 97.9%]: gpio_irq_api.c
Compile [ 98.1%]: hal_tick_overrides.c
Compile [ 98.2%]: gpio_api.c
Compile [ 98.3%]: mbed_crc_api.c
Compile [ 98.4%]: i2c_api.c
[Warning] i2c_api.c@518,19: unused variable 'obj_s' [-Wunused-variable]
Compile [ 98.5%]: qspi_api.c
Compile [ 98.6%]: pinmap.c
Compile [ 98.7%]: lp_ticker.c
Compile [ 98.9%]: mbed_overrides.c
Compile [ 99.0%]: trng_api.c
Compile [ 99.1%]: port_api.c
Compile [ 99.2%]: reset_reason.c
Compile [ 99.3%]: pwmout_api.c
Compile [ 99.4%]: rtc_api.c
Compile [ 99.5%]: serial_api.c
Compile [ 99.7%]: sleep.c
Compile [ 99.8%]: us_ticker.c
Compile [ 99.9%]: stm_spi_api.c
Compile [100.0%]: watchdog_api.c

Link: mbedCrypto
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_import_ec_private_key':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:654: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_rsa_sign':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:3148: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_ecdsa_sign':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:3277: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_cipher_generate_iv':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:3810: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_generate_random':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5375: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o:D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5384: more undefined references to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random' follow

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `mbedtls_psa_crypto_free':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5611: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_free'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_crypto_init':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5678: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_init'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5680: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5658: undefined reference to `mbedtls_entropy_func'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5658: undefined reference to `mbedtls_entropy_init'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5658: undefined reference to `mbedtls_entropy_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[ERROR] c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_import_ec_private_key':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:654: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_rsa_sign':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:3148: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_ecdsa_sign':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:3277: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'

c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_cipher_generate_iv':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:3810: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_generate_random':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5375: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o:D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5384: more undefined references to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random' follow
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `mbedtls_psa_crypto_free':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5611: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_free'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BUILD/NUCLEO_L152RE/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/mbed-os/features/mbedtls/mbed-crypto/platform/COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.o: in function `psa_crypto_init':
D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5678: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_init'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5680: undefined reference to `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5658: undefined reference to `mbedtls_entropy_func'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5658: undefined reference to `mbedtls_entropy_init'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto/.\mbed-os\features\mbedtls\mbed-crypto\platform\COMPONENT_PSA_SRV_IMPL/psa_crypto.c:5658: undefined reference to `mbedtls_entropy_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[mbed] ERROR: "C:\Python27\python.exe" returned error.
       Code: 1
       Path: "D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto"
       Command: "C:\Python27\python.exe -u D:\MbedWorkSpace\mbedCrypto\mbed-os\tools\make.py -t GCC_ARM -m NUCLEO_L152RE --profile mbed-os\tools\profiles\debug.json --source . --build .\BUILD\NUCLEO_L152RE\GCC_ARM-DEBUG"
       Tip: You could retry the last command with "-v" flag for verbose output
---
```

**CMake Output Errors**

I want to compile without Visual Studio as I am using Ubuntu. Can I just download mbed TLS and make it as done with other libraries?

[image: CMake]

Comment: you generate your project for a visual studio version NOT installed on your comuper (VS 2019). You work on LINUX, you can not have visual studio. Try to install Eclipse for C/C++. and choose your eclipse version from CMake

Comment: yes it is VS 2019 but i want to run it on my ubuntu machine so please tell me some other way.

Comment: install Eclipse for C/C++ language https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/sr2/eclipse-ide-cc-developers  and choose eclipse project when you run CMake

Comment: `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_xxx` and `mbedtls_entropy_xxx` functions are defined in the same library that's being compiled: libmbedcrypto. There's a configuration file somewhere that indicates which features to include, and it's inconsistent: if the `psa_xxx` features are enabled (which they need to be for this example) then the `ctr_drbg` and `entropy` features need to be as well. I don't know precisely how that works on Mbed OS. There's not much Mbed OS expertise on Stack Overflow, I suggest asking on the Mbed OS forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a link error because your compiler can not find `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random` function implementation declared in `ctr_drbg.h` (see description [Here](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ctr__drbg_8h.html)):

I Test the library for you. It work after dowing this:

**1-** I download Mbedtls_crt_drbg code here [Here](https://tls.mbed.org/download)
**2-** Extract the zip library in your directory (G:\Cmake\Sources\mbedtls in my case)
**3-** Use `Cmake` (available [Here](https://cmake.org/download/)) to generate a solution (Visual studio 2010 in my case)

[image]

**4-** Open and compile the generated project (in my case `"G:\Cmake\Build\Mbedtls\mbed TLS.sln"`)

**5-** After compilation, see the project `mbedcrypto` output, it generate a `static lib`(in G:\Cmake\Build\Mbedtls\library\Debug\ in my case)

[image]

**6-** You can check if the unreferenced `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random` function in well exported in `static lib`by using visual studio command prompt (or other variant ..)

```
dumpbin /symbols /exports "G:\Cmake\Build\Mbedtls\library\Debug\mbedcrypto.lib" | findstr mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random
```

You must have this:
[image]

**7-** Nothing to do for header since you can include `crt_drbg.h` (in my case : i add `G:\Cmake\Sources\mbedtls\include\mbedtls` to Additional include Path

**8-** Add the `mbedcrypto.lib` to your program. In my case i do this:

```
Right click on my test project -> properties-> Common Properties-> Add New  Reference -> mbedcrypto
```

**9-** Now, i'm able to compile and link with `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random` function:
[image]

*You have to do the same thing for your program*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have downloaded the Mbedtls_crt_drbg and installed Cmake but I am getting errors as shown in the attached screenshot. Is there a way to link the Mbedtls_crt_drbg code using mbed-os itself?

Comment: @Aisha where is the attached screenshot ?

Comment: I have added it but the edit changes are not approved.

Comment: @Aisha Edit your post, and not mine. sorry, I can not approve your edit because you delete lot of important things. At wich stap (4, 5, 6,...) of my answer you have problem ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I thought I am editing mine. I just edit my post.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense: 1. The question is about Mbed OS which has its own build system. Visual Studio and CMake are irrelevant. 2. The missing `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_xxx` functions called from `psa_xxx` functions are defined in the same library. So the problem can't be a missing library. The problem is an incorrect configuration of the library, with some features enabled but not other features that it depends on.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' In this case, you can do some efforts, contribute and poste a complete response in wich you show how to compile from ZERO (like I do). Your answere "The problem in an incorrect configuration, some features, but other features, ..." is a **GENERIC answer** that can be applied on 99% of compilation issues. Finally, the poster check OK, and it work for me, so your remarks do not add any added value to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

For people who still get the error. It is recommended to use the Mbed CLI 2 now of course. Make sure you have installed the [Arm GNU Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/Tools%20and%20Software/GNU%20Toolchain) and add the bin folder of the installation to the environment variables.

I recommend to build the project by directly using cmake:

```
cmake -S . -B cmake_build -GNinja
```

The cmake_build folder is the folder generated when configuring the build target and toolchain.

After that just build the project with the build parameters:

```
cmake --build cmake_build
```

Problem is that the mbed cli includes the toolchain, but the whole C library in the background is missing.